# Is the 2v2 tag necessary?

Tags: discussion, tags

Over in [Should I share unit control in Starcrarft 2 2v2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/62196/should-i-share-unit-control-in-starcrarft-2-2v2) it was tagged with `2v2` which I was unsure about, so I had asked.

I understand what it is now, but I looked over all posts under that tag and they all seem to be Starcraft 2. This seems a bit redundant.

What are the thoughts on tags like this?

Comment: Hah, I was going to come and make this same meta post.

Comment: Renamed [tag:2v2] to [tag:starcraft-2v2] because the former is too generic to be useful and all the affected questions were already tagged [tag:starcraft-2]. starcraft-2-2v2 is... 1 2 many 2s. :)

Comment: @badp Doesn't that leave it redundant still though?

Comment: @Zeno I don't have an answer to that question. That's why I made it a comment. I just specialized the tag to SC2 so it doesn't grow out uncontrollably.

Comment: Since the support for deletion seemed pretty strong, I have gone ahead and removed the tag from its existing questions.  I edited the one question that didn't already contain 2v2 in the text so that it did.

Answer (score 12):

There are only 8 questions with that tag, and all of them (other than 1 that is closed) contain 2v2 either in the title or the question text.  I don't see what the advantage of having the tag is in this case.  While all those questions are certainly focused on 2v2, I'm sure plenty of other questions also have information that would be useful to 2v2 players, so it isn't like someone would want to filter to just those questions.

Comment: Kill it with fire!

Comment: What horrible reasoning. If those other questions have useful information then they should be tagged appropriately. If you wanted to say that 2v2 is bad because more than one game has 2v2 modes and -those- strategies wouldn't share well, I'd get that... but to just say **you** don't think someone would search for it is pretty poor reasoning.

Comment: @corsiKa you misunderstood the post. Tagging them "2v2" does nothing for searchability, as they already contain "2v2" in their titles or question bodies.

Comment: @kotekzot But you can't follow titles. You can follow tags, however.

Comment: @corsiKa If you hover over the tag, you will see that it has 0 followers.  So it isn't just that I think no one will use it that way, it has that nobody has used it that way in the year plus that it has existed.

Comment: @bwarner I'm sure there are plenty of other tags in the same vote. Obscure does not mean useless. Unless there's a compelling reason to remove something, it shouldn't be removed. A passive policy is far superior (and in line with the Stack Exchange philosophy) than an aggressive one.

Comment: @corsiKa There is a compelling reason to remove tags like this.  See http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3800/have-we-not-been-clear-enough-that-meta-tags-are-a-bad-thing

Comment: @bwarner That doesn't apply in the slightest. 2v2 is not a meta tag any more than single player versus multiplayer would be.

Comment: @corsiKa since we are reiterating previously made points, I'll point out that nobody is following that tag anyway.

Comment: @kotekzot I don't see what you're talking about with points previously made. But the fact that no one is following it is not criteria for removal.

Comment: @CorisKa At this point I think this has gone beyond the effective use of comments.  I invite you to discuss this with me or any other Gaming regular in chat to understand how our interpretation is different from yours.

Answer (score -1):

The strategies/problems/et cetera in 1v1 and 2v2 differ greatly from each other, enough so that I think it warrants having a special tag for it.

However, I think it would be a good idea to rename the tag to [starcraft-2-2v2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-2-2v2)

Comment: What about a tag for Heart of the Swarm 8 player games with 2 person teams?  Would that be starcraft-2-2-2v2v2v2?

Comment: Hmm I'm confused then. Does that mean we should start tagging say Skyrim posts along with the difficulty the game is set at, as well? Strategies change also depending on the difficulty of many games, but I never really see difficulties tagged.

Comment: @Zeno I would label the difference that the 2v2 has it's own distinct set of problems and solutions which differ considerable from 1v1, but I do see your point.

Comment: @bwarner Yeah, my solution may result in some extreme cases, some refinement is required.